# AlarmManager fails when initiated from a service in Marshmallow and above

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Am trying to set up a simple Alarm Manager in a service.

## test_cases.

If i start the Alarm manager from an Activity, it works

```
    Intent intentzz = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homev2.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentzz, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

However, if i try to start the same from a service, it just does not, and i do not get any errors

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    return null;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("we here", "here");

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1,intent1, 0);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You are sending intent to which class?

Comment: SettingsActivity.class its in the code above@amitava

Comment: Ok, I am not getting something; what is Homev2.class where you are sending intent in activity?

Comment: The first code opens a Home2.class activity, which works fine. The second code, which is in a Service should open a SettingsActivity, but does not.

Comment: I could not replicate your problem. Please provide the code where you started the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1,intent1, 0);
```

To this:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,intent1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case